# How to detect other outlook events such as "Forward as attachment", "Reply with Meeting"

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Out of the box outlook provides the following:

```
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)this._mailItem).Reply += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply);
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)this._mailItem).ReplyAll += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(MailItem_ReplyAll);
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)this._mailItem).CustomAction += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CustomActionEventHandler(MailItem_CustomAction);
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)this._mailItem).Forward += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ForwardEventHandler(MailItem_Forward);
```

However, is there a way to detect other events such as:

- Reply with Meeting
- Forward as Attachment

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I'm facing the very same Issue.  I need to block certain emails from being forwarded as attachments.

I'm currently studying this article [Understanding COM Event Handling](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/9014/understanding-com-event-handling) as well as looking into using Redemption.

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific events for those actions but the standard Reply and Forward events will still fire. You can also tell that they clicked those buttons by inspecting the item type or attachment in the newly created item.

Answer (score 0):

OOM exposes `ForwardAsAttachment` as an event with the dispid of `0x0000F618`, it is just the type library does not expose it. "Reply with meeting" is `0x0000F5FD`.

You can hook those events using `IConnectionPointContainer` / `IConnectionPoint` using raw COM - you can see the events firing in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author): select an item, click Item button on the OutlookSpy toolbar, go to the Events tab, click "Forward As Attachment", see the event logged in "Events Log" list at the bottom of the Item window.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) is an option, it exposes these events on the [SafeMailItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeMailItem.htm) object:

```
private SafeMailItem _sItem;
private MailItem _oItem;
...
_oItem = _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
_sItem = new SafeMailItem();
_sItem.Item = _oItem;
_sItem.ForwardAsAttachment += OnForwardAsAttachment;
...
private void OnForwardAsAttachment(object Forward, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MailItem newMessage = (MailItem)Forward;
    if (OlSensitivity.olConfidential == _oItem.Sensitivity)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Confidential message '{_oItem.Subject}' cannot be forwarded");
        Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        newMessage.Subject = _oItem.Subject;
        newMessage.Body = $"Please see the attached message '{_oItem.Subject}'.";
    }
}
```