# How do I use IConnectionPoint to capture the "Forward As Attachment" event?

Tags: c#, outlook, com, outlook-addin, addin-express

In this article, [How to detect Outlook Events ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44616074/8321222), [Dmitry Streblechenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko) outlines how to subscribe to Outlook Events not listed in the TypeLibrary.

Would these be the steps to follow?

1. Use some Ole Viewer to locate the GUID of the object in question.
2. Pass that GUID to **IConnectionPointContainer** in order to retrieve an **IConnectionPoint** object.
3. Call Advise / UnAdvise (etc.)

Does that look about right?  Does anyone have any sample code?

Comment: What language are you developing in?

Comment: @MichaelGunter:  C#

Yeah, that piece of information would help :)

It's a COM Add-In.  I'm using Add-In Express, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried to contact them for implementing the event in their toolset?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev
I opted to get "Outlook Redemption."  I got everything going in literally less than 15 minutes!!

I plan to post the solution.  However, I am working on an additional solution to this as well, that I plan to post.  I'm an old COM/C++ guy.  This would have been no problem had I not been forced to work in c#/.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemEvents_10` GUID to pass to `IConnectionPointContainerFindConnectionPoint` is `{0006302B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` (you can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - I am its author).
`ItemEvents` is `{0006303A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`